# Python, try except, print error line #

Tags: python, try-except

I would like when there is an error that it would display what line the error occurred at.  I am unsure how I can obtain the line # that the error happened at though.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
def main():
    while True:
       try:
           function1()
           function2()
           function3()
       except:
           print('error occur at line ' + str(errorline))
```

Comment: Inspecting an interpreter stack is a way to go.

[https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`traceback.extract_tb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_tb):

```
import sys
import traceback
try:
    # Your code
except:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[-1]
    print(traceback.extract_tb(tb, limit=1)[-1][1])
```

I added `limit=1` for efficiency, to avoid loading the (possibly) huge traceback. You can't avoid indexing the list (`[-1]` to get the last element) though.

Comment: `extract_tb` takes a *limit* param that can be used instead of indexing the array. Also, according to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), if you store the `traceback` reference returned by `exc_info()` you should *always* delete it or it creates a circular reference that is difficult to garbage collect.

Comment: @aruisdante only important in Python 2.